# Which clock does Excel VBA use?

Tags: excel, vba, windows, time

I noticed that the time in Excel or Excel VBA is 1 second *ahead* of my Windows time in the right hand corner of my screen. If I open a new workbook, add the code below and run the code, the time is continiously updated and can be compared to the time in the right hand corner of the screen.

```
Sub test()


For f = 1 To 100000

Debug.Print Time

Next f


End Sub
```

The function =NOW() can be added to the worksheet. This returns the same time as the Excel VBA time.

I also have updated my system time with several sources aldo this make no difference.

Is there any explanation for this difference?

See this video for the time difference:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/y6lbethzce5110x/IMG_4714.MOV?dl=0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to synchronize Excel time with Windows time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63993799/how-to-synchronize-excel-time-with-windows-time)

Comment: @IInspectable hello, in the current question I isolated the problem to the difference between excel Time and the clock in the right hand corner.

Comment: If you need to update your previous question there's an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63993799/edit) link right underneath it.

Comment: @IInspectable i made a remark at the end with no response. I thought it would be more clear to isolate the problem in a new question. So it would had been better to modify the original question to the question above?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the issue. It is synchron here:

[image]

`Time` is using the correct windows system time. There is only this one "clock" called system time.

Any differences you see might be a result of calculation time, CPU ressources etc. Runtime of your program might be an issue too. Eg if your code needs some amount of time to execute (and it will), you will have some lag between reading the system time and printing it in the immediate window.

Comment: @ Peh Thanks. I have added a link to a movie with my code and clock. I can imagine Excel is a few milliseconds behind due to process time, although in my case it is ahead. I can reproduce the issue on another pc too.

Comment: Well, the Windows clock in the task bar might not be a time critical process and accurate enough. Nevertheless it relies on the same system clock.